# Change destination folder of JAR files in Netbeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, directory

I'm working on a multiproject solution for a client and we're trying to have all our builds automatically go into a predetermined BIN folder.  All the C++ projects were easily enough moved over but the Java side has proven not so easily configured.  When I go to the project's properties and go to Build->Packaging the "JAR File:" text box shows a read-only text-box pointing to "dist/App.jar" (which I would like to change to "../../../bin/App.jar".  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the dist-folder by editing the `dist.dir` key in the `project.properties`file which is located in the `nbproject` directory from

```
dist.dir=dist
```

to

```
dist.dir=../../../bin
```

In my case the key is in line 24. The name of the jar-file itself is determined by the `dist.jar` key, if you would need to rename the file aswell.

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks Pit! Strange how they don't let you do it through the "properties" dialog...

Comment: You can view it in the properties-dialog, but not change it. Definitely something they have to change in future versions! I'm glad I could help ;)

Comment: It's important to mantion that the directory at this path will be totally cleaned(all files removed).

Answer (score 2):

add into build.xml

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <copy file="${dist.jar}" todir="drive\path\"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check under the menu

[Run] --> [Set project configuration] --> [Customize]
You have plenty of options to change there, it is easy than that.

Good luck