# Changing .jar creation directory

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to change the location where my .jar file is compiled to in netbeans IDE. Also i would like to know how to make a file passed on to the .jar instead of not being included in the compilation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416445/change-destination-folder-of-jar-files-in-netbeans-7 
is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 1):

To change the distribution path of the jar/war file you have to edit the xml file {project_folder/nbproject/project.properties}

The property `dist.dir` is the destination of the war file when created.

Changing this property to dist.dir=c:/mydir/dist will result in this after building your project:

```
Created dir: c:\mydir\dist
Building jar: c:\mydir\dist\Test.war
do-dist:
dist:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)
```

In order to remove a file from being included in your project jar/war file just remove the checkbox `package` next to it in the `Project Properties>Libraries>Compile` screen