# Netbeans 12 with Ant how to change default lib folder

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I'm using Netbeans 12 with Ant to build my apps. The default folder for libraries is 'lib'. Is there any simple and straightforward way to change it? For example I need to put my libraries in the same folder together with my main .jar when building.

I've checked some older related questions here, but answers were either too complicated or not actual anymore (provided links not working etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the NetBeans Project Wizard, select **File > New Project > Java with Ant > Java Application**, and click **Next>**.

The wizard screen will include a checkbox labeled **Use Dedicated Folder for Storing Libraries**. To change the default folder for libraries check that box, and then the following field labelled **Libraries Folder** will become enabled. You can replace the default value of **.\lib** with your own directory. For example:

[image: non default lib folder]

You can use the same approach when creating web applications and enterprise applications. The field settings are sticky, so be sure to check that the values remain appropriate when creating subsequent projects.

I couldn't find any NetBeans 12 documentation on this, but the NetBeans 8.2 documentation remains valid. See [section 6.6 Sharing a Library with Other Users](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/create_japps.htm#NBDAG455) for details:

> You can configure most standard Java SE, Web, and Enterprise projects
> in a way that makes it easy to share libraries with other users. You
> can specify a location for libraries on which the project relies. You
> can also specify how the libraries are referenced from your project...

Note that this approach will not put (what you called) **main.jar** in the specified libraries folder. That will still be placed directly under the **dist** directory. If you want to change that behavior I think you might need to modify some NetBeans Ant script(s).

Comment: Unfortunately for me it is not working as expected. So, in short, my goal is to have library jar in the same folder as main app jar with a relative path (so I can just move those 2 jars (app and lib) in any folder or environment (Windows/Linux)). What I did: in NetBeans 12.3 created a new project with Ant, in your specified field I put . (also tried ./ ) instead of default ./lib, then right click in Libraries -> Add Project... Then built... As a result, project's added as library .jar is in **dist/lib** folder again.. although expected result is to have both jars in just **dist** folder

Comment: Gotcha. [1] FYI, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416772/2985643) tells you how to specify a target directory other than **dist**. However, that still does not resolve your concern because your app's jar and the dependent libraries would still end up in separate directories, and I see no way to specify the target **lib** directory. [2] Also, the actual copying to **dist** during the build process is done by the internal NetBeans jar file **org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar** rather than a modifiable Ant script, as I had incorrectly suggested in my answer.